# How to update a node in lisp

Tags: lisp, elisp, common-lisp

I am manipulating a tree in lisp.
I thought that function parameters were mutable..

For example I create a list fs and a function to add an element into it without returning the list itself (I really don't want to return it).

```
(defparameter fs '(1 2 3 4))

(defun addtolist (fs)
  (append fs '(6))
)

(print (addtolist fs))
;;(1 2 3 4 6)
(print fs)
;;(1 2 3 4)
```

I don't understand why the list is not keeping the modification after.
Any ideas?

Comment: You said: 'I thought that function parameters were mutable..' Why did you think that? Then you said '...create a list fs': you did't create a list `fs`. You created a variable `fs`, which then has a list as its value.

Answer (score 2):

First, a note on ANSI Common Lisp usage:

```
(defparameter fs '(1 2 3 4))
```

Here, `defparameter` introduces `fs` as a dynamic variable. One of the things which this means is that the symbol `fs` itself is marked "special", which affects all of its subsequent bindings.

```
(defun addtolist (fs)
  (append fs '(6))
)
```

The consequence is that here, the function parameter `fs` isn't a lexical variable as ordinarily expected, but still a dynamic variable. That is almost certainly unintentional, and can change the behavior.

This problem is prevented with a naming discipline, the most common one being the "earmuffs convention": a leading and trailing asterisk:

```
(defparameter *my-dynamic-variable* 42)
```

Note how the standard dynamic variables in Common Lisp are named this way: `*standard-output*`, `*print-base*`, `*random-state*`, `*package*`, and numerous others.

> I don't understand why the list is not keeping the modification after.

It is because the `append` function itself computes a new list, leaving the old one alone. (The new list can use pieces of the old one, but the old one is undisturbed.)

In that particular case, the destructive version of `append` could be used, namely the `nconc` function.  `nconc` will rewrite the tail of the original list so that it points to `(6)`. However, there are two problems:

1. The input list is a literal. Modifying a literal is **undefined behavior** according to the ANSI Common Lisp spec. There is no way to modify the literal `'(1 2 3 4)` into `(1 2 3 4 6)`. Literal objects must be treated read-only.
2. The approach is not general. Even if we use `nconc` in `addtolist`, and ensure we do not feed it literals (to avoid undefined behavior), our `addtolist` will be broken. For instance, it cannot add to an empty list!

In Lisp, we do not have "bag-like" lists that can be appended without being returned. The empty list is represented by a symbol, the symbol `nil`, which isn't a container that has nothing in it. We cannot change `nil` into a non-empty list.

A "bag-like" list is emulated in Lisp by storing a list in a *generalized place* (some `setf`-able location, such as a variable).  When updating the list, we assign the new version back into the variable.

When objects have to have lists of associated objects, that is encapsulated. For instance, with structures:

```
(defstruct notifier
  (listeners))      ;; a notifier has listeners

(defun add-listener (notifier listener)
  (pushnew listener (notifier-listeners notifier)))

(defun remove-listener (notifier listener)
  (setf (notifier-listeners notifier) ;; candidate for define-modify-macro
        (remove listener (notifier-listeners notifier))))

[1]> (defvar *n* (make-notifier))
*N*
[2]> *n*
#S(NOTIFIER :LISTENERS NIL)
[3]> (add-listener *n* 4)
(4)
[4]> (add-listener *n* 5)
(5 4)
[5]> *n*
#S(NOTIFIER :LISTENERS (5 4))
[6]> (add-listener *n* 6)
(6 5 4)
[7]> *n*
#S(NOTIFIER :LISTENERS (6 5 4))
[8]> (remove-listener *n* 5)
(6 4)
[9]> *n*
#S(NOTIFIER :LISTENERS (6 4))
[10]> (remove-listener *n* 6)
(4)
[11]> (remove-listener *n* 4)
NIL
[12]> *n*
#S(NOTIFIER :LISTENERS NIL)
```

"Bag-like" lists are a tremendous disadvantage, because there is no way to use them without engaging in **imperative programming**. All operations on such a list are destructive manipulations. This is unacceptably cumbersome, inefficient and error-prone for the kinds of usage of lists in Lisp, such as for generating and transforming deeply-nested syntactic structures.

As you can see in the above example, we can easily obtain a "bag-like" list if we "park" a functional list into some well-known location, such as the slot of a structure, and treat that slot as the "bag".  The destructive bag *operations* like append and remove translate into *assignments* to that location.

Answer (score 1):

Not all functions modify their arguments; in fact, most (like `append`) don't.

I think what you are looking for is `nconc`.

Comment: Then how can I add the element in the list and keep the modification without returning the list?

Comment: Thanks. If the list fs is empty, the value is not saved. How can I fix this case?